# How to open a hyperlink in separate browser tab in Coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have three different Hyperlinks on a web page

- Planning.
- Solutions.
- Contact Us.

I want to open them in separate browser tab one by one using codedUI.
i have written the above code to obtain the list of Hyperlink

```
           HtmlControl Hyperlink = new HtmlControl(browser);
           Hyperlink.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlType,"Hyperlink");
           UITestControlCollection controls = Hyperlink.FindMatchingControls();
           foreach(UITestControl control in controls)
                    {
                       if (control is HtmlHyperlink)
                        {
                          HtmlHyperlink link = (HtmlHyperlink)control;
                          if(link.InnerText=="Planning"|| link.InnerText== "Solutions")
                             {
                                  //separate Tab logic goes here
                              }
                        } 
                     }
```

I need the help related to opening a hyperlink in new browser tab. Is it possible in CodedUI ?

Answer (score 2):

By default if you click the mouse middle button (or click the scroll wheel), it opens a link in new tab. I would modify your code as below in this case,

```
if(link.InnerText=="Planning"|| link.InnerText== "Solutions")
{
    //Open Link in New tab, by clicking middle button 
    Mouse.Click(link, MouseButtons.Middle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a couple different ways. I would use @Prageeth-Saravan 's approach first to see if it works because it's easier and actually tests your UI. You could also:

- Get the URL from the found link control
- Send the "New tab" keyboard shortcut
- **Reinstantiate your browser window object** to be sure it's pointing to the new tab
- Navigate to that URL

The reason why I bolded step 3 is regardless of approach, if you intend to assert or interact with *anything* in a new tab you're going to have to remember that the CodedUI software will still be "Looking" at the old tab until you reinitialize it.